# Get XML's child nodes automatically in SoapUI Groovy Script

Tags: xml, groovy, automated-tests, soapui

I've two test steps in SoapUI.groovy script step and SOAP request step. This is how request's body looks like:

```
<int:user>
     <name>James</name>
     <surname>Brown</surname>
     <age>100</age>
     <status>active </status>
</int:User>
```

I want to generate a string in groovy script, which will contain all the nodes of the body  (in this example `str = "namesurnameagestatus"`); and a string with values of the attributes; (in this example `str = "JamesBrown100active"`); I have to create first string manually. For second String I use this:

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context )
    def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder(step.getPropertyValue("request") )  
    holder.getNodeValue("//name");  //for the name attribute
```

etc.

I want to do this proccess automatically within a loop.

for example:

```
object =  Get Node Values of Body
count = object.size();
// some loop
for(count times){ 
     object.get(i).  get value;
     //other code
}
```

Something like this. Any solutions? I've dived deep in some other solutions, but was not able to find correct code/behaviour.

Comment: So confusing your question is. Can you simplify it please? What is the use case? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Rao how to simplify it more? I want to get nodes of the request's body automatically.Try to achieve to get all child nodes' values as array or as map or as something. I found out this [link](https://www.soapui.org/scripting-properties/tips-tricks.html#3-1-Iterate-nodes) .tried holder.getNodeValues("//body")  method,but it returns only one null object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Help of Gaurav khurana I found out the solution.

if I want to get all values of the elements in the body containter.I do this :

```
    def gu=new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
    def res = context.expand('${First Step#request}')
    //log.info res
    def holder = gu.getXmlHolder(res)
    def val=holder.getNodeValues("//soap:Body/*")
    def  allvalues=""
    for(values in val)
    {
        allvalues=allvalues+values
    }
    log.info allvalues
```

The way to get the names for the elements( in this case "name surname age status" do the folowing :

```
  def gal = holder.getDomNodes("//" + space + "/*");

  for (values in gal) {
  log.info(values.getTagName());
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your use case is , you will combine all attributes like name,surname,etc and also their values.

Then you will try to check if actual=expected !!

Lets assume the sample xml is below

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <ConversionRateResponse xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">
       <name>James</name>
     <surname>Brown</surname>
     <age>100</age>
     <status>active </status>
      </ConversionRateResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The below groovy code will give all the values together. Just replace the "first Step" with the name of your step

```
def gu=new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
def res = context.expand('${First Step#response}')
//log.info res
def holder = gu.getXmlHolder(res)
def val=holder.getNodeValues("//*[local-name()='ConversionRateResponse']/*")
def  allvalues=""
for(values in val)
{
    allvalues=allvalues+values
}
log.info allvalues
```

Output of the above code is

```
Sat Nov 25 15:57:31 IST 2017:INFO:JamesBrown100active
```

please note this will not be the right way of validation as tomorrow if the attribute is not passed or is optional then script will fail.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I tried the same thing but problem is that my result is null.  after getNodeValues the size of the array is 0.

Comment: the problem is solved.Thank you.I was trying to get all node values from body container. I changed your code for my request.I want all elements from body,so I use def val = holder.getNodeValues("//soap:Body/*") .

Comment: oh okies.. i think you can upvote but it will not be reflected as of now.. But once your reputation reaches a level, it will show to others